# mongo db inner join + filter the joining documment

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 documents: boundaries, roles and users, each user has multiple roles and a boundary and each role has 1 boundary.
User:

```
{
  uuid: String,
  name: String,
  rolesBoundary: [
                   roles: [String], // this is the roles the user has for this boundary
                   boundary: String // this is the uuid of the boundary
                 ]
}
```

Role:

```
{
  uuid: string,
  name: String
}
```

Boundary:

```
{
  name: String,
  uuid: String
}
```

I want to show a list of boundaries and I want to include one more field which is the roles of the logged-in User.
this is what I have done so far:

```
{
  await BoundaryModel.aggregate([
        {
            $graphLookup: {
                from: 'users',
                startWith: '$uuid',
                connectFromField: 'uuid',
                connectToField: 'boundaryAccess.roles',
                as: 'roles'
            }
        }
    ]);
}
```

I know it is wrong because I haven't filter for the logged in user and roles array is empty. any suggesstion please?

Comment: second try: 
`db.users.aggregate()
    .match({uuid: 4})
    .project({"boundaryAcess": 1, "_id": 0})
    .graphLookup({
          from: "boundaries",
          startWith: "$uuid",
          connectFromField: "boundaryAcess",
          connectToField: "uuid",
          as: "roles"
    })`
but still getting empty roles field :(

Answer (score 0):

Found it with couples of tries, I shouldn't use graph lookup, I used lookup instead

```
exports.getUserBoundaries = async (id) => {
const boundariesList = await BoundaryModel.aggregate()
    .lookup({
        from: "users",
        localField: "uuid",
        foreignField: "rolesBoundary.boundary",
        as: "user_doc"
    })
    .match({
        $or: [
            {"user_doc.uuid": {$exists: false}}, // get result even if the boundary 
                                                 // doesn't have a uuid which is what  
                                               // I want because I want all boundaries
            {"user_doc.uuid": id} // and we get also the boundaries with current user id
        ]
    })
```